# How much does google know about me if I visit a website with Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

If I visit a website that contains Google Analytics, information about my visit is sent to Google, which is used to provide the website's owner with demographic and other statistics about his/her site visitors. However, I'm wondering if and how my visit will affect Google's knowledge **about me, specifically**. For example, will it affect the parameters that are used for Google's personalized search results that are presented to me? And is Google able to tell that it was me who visited a website (i.e. attribute that visit to my Google account) that has Analytics enabled, even if I **didn't** access the website via a Google search?
And does the answer differ depending on whether I'm logged in to a Google account on the computer I'm using to access the website, and whether I'm browsing in private mode?

Answer (score 1):

Google will know nothing about you (or at least it should not) as it would go against their privacy policy about collecting any information that could personally identify you and other visitors. Of course, that does not mean that the site itself won't prompt you for some personal information, for example if you fill out a form, and if the site administrator inadvertently collects information about you and sends it to GA, then that is another issue (also one that goes against Google's privacy policies). You can read more about this in section 7 here: http://www.google.ca/analytics/terms/us.html.

Google Analytics alone does not do remarketing, so it won't be able to target you with specific ads or content. There may be some other tools used alongside GA, but I don't think GA by itself has that ability.

Additionally, I don't believe GA data has any bearing on searches done with Google search engine, whether you are logged in to your Google Account or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  
Just to be clear, does that also mean that the data collected by Google Analytics will have no effect whatsoever on my personal 'filter bubble' (i.e. my personalized search results) when I use Google search?